# Port 4444 is busy, please choose a free port and specify it using -port option error while trying to initiate Selenium Grid Hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, grid, selenium-grid

I am getting below error code on my CMD while I am starting selenium grid hub. The error is as follows:

```
Port 4444 is busy, please choose a free port for the hub and specify it using -port option
```

Comment: did you try checking which service is using that port? and may be shut that service down

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Port 4444 is busy, please choose a free port and specify it using -port option
```

...implies that the *Selenium Grid Hub* was unable to initiatethe service on port **4444**.

Some more information about the *Test Environment* and your *Test Configuration* would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However it seems the port **4444** is occupied by some other service/activity within your *Test Environment*.

---

### Solution

The easiest approach would be to spin off the *Selenium Grid Hub* on some other free port instead of the default port **4444**:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -port 5786
```